# How to select an option from drop down in selenium webdriver. The element is not a 'select' element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; fill: rgb(224, 224, 224); height: 24px; width: 24px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 22px; -webkit-user-select: none;"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path></svg>

<path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
```

I've attempted, using as a container, using the action class to hover over, using the select class but none seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is not a select element then it's still a WebElement. Display the options and find the xpath for the option and if you need to select a particular one, use the find by text as follows. You may need to have a wait in place to wait for the option to display.

Example: 
1. Click on the drop down element to display the list of items. 
2. Use the following to find the option and then select it

```
WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'THE OPTION TEXT YOURE LOOKING FOR')]"));
yourElement.click();
```